# Trying to decipher a slim view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

I inherited a Rails applications, that uses SLIM. I am trying to get up to speed on SLIM, but I am having a little trouble with one of the statements in a view:

```
= f.select :location_ids, locations, {}, { multiple: true}
```

This is part of a form, where you can select from different locations.

:locations_id will return an array

locations is the array containing the locations to select from (i know where it's computed in the code)

{ multiple: true} allows the user to make multiple selections, if set to false, it limits it to a single selection

A couple of questions:

1. What is the additional empty {} for?
2. If the user makes only a single selection, will the :location_ids be always returned as an array?

## Edit:

Using the original:

```
= f.select :location_ids, locations, {}, { multiple: true}
```

Here's what I got in the params:

...."location_ids"=>["", "1407948222_686938_location"]

An Array,

When I changed it to:

```
= f.select :location_ids, locations, {}, { multiple: false}
```

Here's what I got in the params:

```
"location_ids"=>"1450908309_866831_location"
```

A string.

Answer (score 0):

Edited for clarification, sorry about that, I got distracted halfway though writing my answer:

First, yeah the {} does nothing. It's the spot for "options" according to the documentation, so you'd place things like `include_blank: true` there, but since it's an empty hash nothing happens. Normally I'd give it `nil` or leave it blank.

For your second question, like you said in the comment below, multiple true submits as an array, false submits as a string. Nothin' too fancy there.

On a broader note, slim ultimately compiles to an html.erb file, so you're really just looking at

```
<%= f.select(:location_ids, locations, {}, { multiple: true}) %>
```

Just 'cleaned up'.

Comment: Question #2, was what would happen if I changed it to false. I know the answer now, it gets submitted as a string, not an array. On question #1, I was just trying to understand what the an empty {} as the third param does.